# Reading a text file from a networked computer

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and I am working on my first application. The application needs to be able to read and write to a txt file on a networked computer. My application has buttons that are going to control different things and the file is going to contain the states of my toggle buttons (0 for off, 1 for on). I don't know if this is even possible and everywhere I have looked only discusses reading from the phone. I need the file on the computer because the computer needs to access the state changes as well for its own interface.

Comment: Well I was trying to see if it was even possible or how I cod even go about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't usually provide written code in SO, but there are exceptions like this that I have similar code ready :)

You need to have a web server running on your computer(Windows: [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), Mac: [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html), Linux: Apache(or httpd on non-debian based distros. Available via package manager of your choice))

And then write a simple PHP script to write and read from the file ([PHP Files and I/O](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_files.htm)).

After you did it only thing that remains, is to access the file from your phone.. There are lots of tutorials on the web on connecting Android and PHP. But I like this one better ([How to connect Android with PHP, MYSQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/).

And, (Just because I'm too generous :p), here is the source code to one of my programs that does nearly the same thing and was built by the help of the tutorials above: [Feniix on Github](http://www.github.com/minlite13/feniix) !